# Procedure calling gone bad - Statement Ignored

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have the following procedure to insert users in a table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ELR_ADD_USER
                  (I_NAME          IN VARCHAR2,
                   I_MORADA        IN VARCHAR2,
                   I_BIRTHDATE     IN DATE,
                   I_COUNTRY       IN VARCHAR2,
                   O_ID            OUT NUMBER,
                   O_ERROR_MSG     OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
 ERROR_NULL           EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  
IF I_NAME IS NULL OR
   I_MORADA IS NULL OR
   I_BIRTHDATE IS NULL OR
   I_COUNTRY IS NULL THEN
   
       RAISE ERROR_NULL;
END IF;

   O_ID := ELR_seq_USER_ID.nextval;
   
IF O_ID IS NULL
  RAISE ERROR_NULL;
END IF;

  INSERT INTO ELR_USERS
  VALUES (O_ID, I_NOME, I_MORADA, I_BIRTHDATE, I_COUNTRY);

EXCEPTION 
   WHEN ERROR_NULL THEN
     O_ERROR_MSG := 'NULL FIELDS';
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
     O_ERROR_MSG := 'UNEXPECTED ERROR: '|| sqlerrm;
     
END;
/
```

I think the procedure and it's syntax are correct. However when I'm trying to call it with:

```
DECLARE
     P_NAME         VARCHAR2(50);
     P_MORADA       VARCHAR2(50);
     P_BIRTHDATE    DATE;
     P_COUNTRY      VARCHAR2(20);
     P_ID           NUMBER(20);
     P_ERROR_MSG    VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN

ELR_ADD_USER('ED WARNER','CENAS Street',SYSDATE,
                      'China', P_ID, P_ERROR_MSG);

IF P_ERROR_MSG IS NOT NULL THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR: '||P_ERROR_MSG);
END IF;

END;
/
```

I get the following message:

[image]

Is there something wrong with the calling or the procedure itself?

Comment: then it compiled with errors.  re-compile and run "show errors"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ORA-06550` followed by `PLS-00905` is clearly a **compilation error**. The procedure is in **INVALID** state.

Recompile the procedure, and use **SHOW ERRORS** to get the complete error details.

`SHOW ERROR PROCEDURE RMS_MM.ELR_ADD_USER` or simply `SHOW ERRORS`

For [example](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora06550.php),

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TestProc
  2  AS
  3    vnum number;
  4  BEGIN
  5    vnum := vAnotherNum;
  6  END;
  7  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> execute TestProc();
BEGIN TestProc(); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00905: object EXAMPLE.TESTPROC is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

SQL> show error procedure TestProc;
Errors for PROCEDURE TESTPROC:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
5/1  PL/SQL: Statement ignored
5/9  PLS-00201: identifier 'VANOTHERNUM' must be declared
```

Comment: show error procedure ELR_ADD_USER; or show errors procedure ELR_ADD_USER; both are invalid statements :x

Comment: `SHOW ERROR PROCEDURE RMS_MM.ELR_ADD_USER` or simply `SHOW ERRORS`